# Qt5, opengl es 2 extensions required

Tags: android, qt, opengl-es

I am developing an Android application based on Qt5.4/QtQuick 2 and opengles 2.
I installed textureinsgnode in order to check how well it runs in my target device(as my app is making massive use of FBOs) and I am getting 18 FPS. I checked on a Samsung SM-T535 and I get around 47/48 FPS, and my application looks like colapsed when trying to make any user action.

I checked the extension available in both devices(my target and Samsung tablet) by:

```
QOpenGLFramebufferObject *createFramebufferObject(const QSize &size) {
        QSet<QByteArray> extensions = QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->extensions();
        foreach (QByteArray extension, extensions) {
            qDebug() << extension;
        }
        QOpenGLFramebufferObjectFormat format;
        format.setAttachment(QOpenGLFramebufferObject::CombinedDepthStencil);
        format.setSamples(4);
        return new QOpenGLFramebufferObject(size, format);
    }
```

And I am getting a very sort list of extensions in the target device If I compare with Samsung tablet list in the same point:

> "GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8"
>   "GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture" "GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil"
>   "GL_ARM_rgba8" "GL_OES_vertex_half_float" "GL_OES_EGL_image"
>   "GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer" "GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture"
>   "GL_OES_depth_texture" "GL_KHR_debug" "GL_ARM_mali_shader_binary"
>   "GL_OES_depth24" "GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888"
>   "GL_EXT_blend_minmax" "GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod"
>   "GL_OES_EGL_image_external" "GL_EXT_robustness" "GL_OES_texture_npot"
>   "GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map" "GL_ARM_mali_program_binary"
>   "GL_EXT_debug_marker" "GL_OES_get_program_binary"
>   "GL_OES_standard_derivatives" "GL_OES_EGL_sync"

I installed an NME(3.4.4, so based in opengl es 1.1) application (BunnyMark) and I can get around 45-48 FPS.

By basing in this tests, I can think the target device is having some problem with opengl es 2 but I am not able to find (I was googleing) on any place what opengl es 2 extension requires Qt5.4 to work properly.

The question: What are the opengl es 2 extensions required by Qt5.4 and is there a way to check it?

Comment: No "extension" is actually required. Which GPU does your target platform have?

Comment: According with "adb shell dumpsys | grep GLES" it is a "GLES: ARM, Mali-450 MP, OpenGL ES 2.0"

Comment: @peppe Did you find anything?

Comment: No, except that perhaps that example might bee too heavy. Have you tried a purely 2d example?